# hal.dll file deleted .. how to recover the PC ..?

Tags: windows, virus

Because of the viral infection, if the PC gets crashed,
 On start-up, it shows the msg on Console screen on start-up, saying, "hal.dll file is missing/deleted, press alt+ctrl+delete to restart the system", (XP OS)

In such a case, how to recover the PC other than installing fresh copy of OS (completely formatting the local disk-drive) ?

The "repair" option with XP installation CD can't fix it.

Comment: Is it the only solution, to format the OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to manually replace the hal.dll by using the [recovery console](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/rconsole.htm).

once you get a prompt, try

```
expand d:\i386\hal.dl_ c:\windows\system32
```

where d: is your optical disc. Restart, and it should (hopefully) be ok.

Answer (score -1):

boot with ubuntu or other linux OS, and take another version of hal.dll and copy it to your system 32, I believe this should work

Comment: You should verify your solution works before you submit it.

Comment: You can't just take a random hal.dll from somewhere and slap it in.

Comment: Where should this version of hal.dll come from and why can it only be copied using Linux?